# DBCC CHECKDB WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY option runs slower compared to a Full DBCC CHECKDB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dbcc-checkdb

Is it possible for `DBCC CHECKDB WITH PHYSICAL_ONLY` to run slower compared to a full `DBCC CHECKDB`? The platform is SQL Server 2014 SP2.

Comment: Was the load on the server the same for both tests?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, no.

[DBCC CHECKDB Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql)

> PHYSICAL_ONLY
>   Limits the checking to the integrity of the physical structure of the page and record headers and the allocation consistency of the database. This check is designed to provide a small overhead check of the physical consistency of the database, but it can also detect torn pages, checksum failures, and common hardware failures that can compromise a user's data.
>   A full run of DBCC CHECKDB may take considerably longer to complete than earlier versions.

I confirmed this by running DBCC CHECKDB against the same 50GB database twice, once with PHYSICAL_ONLY specified, and the other without any options set. The results:

```
 With physical_only:
 SQL Server Execution Times:
 CPU time = 46894 ms,  elapsed time = 61546 ms.

 All checks: 
 SQL Server Execution Times:
 CPU time = 247964 ms,  elapsed time = 263678 ms.
```

Having said all that, do you see that PHYSICAL_ONLY takes longer than a full check?

EDIT: Here's the results for a 320GB database:

```
With physical_only:
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 552805 ms,  elapsed time = 1218867 ms.

All checks:
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 2074875 ms,  elapsed time = 3007516 ms.
```

So, no - PHYSICAL_ONLY on databases larger than 200GB is not slower than a full check.

Comment: From my personal experience and research that will be the case but our production DBA tested it in production and pointed out the physical_only is only faster for small DBs but for larger DBs (>200 GB) the physical_only becames slower. I just want to see if anyone ever seen the similar behavior certainly not what I experienced when I was a DBA in my pervious life.

Comment: Added more information to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Steve, we still have to figure out how our production DBA managed to get the conclusion of full check is faster. Will update you again if we manage to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no: it does a subset of the tasks so should be faster.

*But* it might be faster for small databases (where "small" is defined depending on IO setup (how much cache does your RAID/SAN/... have?), and perhaps available memory) if you run it first, due to it priming caches ahead of the normally longer process.